# How can I set `path.expand` to begin at my working directory?

Tags: r, path

I'm using a Mac. The `path.expand` function is several folders removed from my desired working directory. For example:

`path.expand`('~')

[1] "/Users/my.name"

I'd like to change it to something like this:

`path.expand`('~')

[1] "/Users/my.name/drive/R/project/sub.folder"

How can I go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: "~" as special meaning. What special meaning is it? How can it be used *as part of* a path, in the case presented?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: `path.expand('~/drive/R/project/sub.folder')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tilde is, in all unix-sen (including macos), special in that it refers to what the operating system considers the home directory (via the  env var `HOME`).

There are two types of answers to this. Can it be done? Perhaps, sure even. Should it be done? There will likely be unintended consequences (that may be hard to troubleshoot and/or workaround), so likely not.

This works on my ubuntu box:

```
me@mybox:/some/path$ Rscript -e 'Sys.getenv("HOME")'
[1] "/home/me"
me@mybox:/some/path$ HOME=/tmp/ Rscript -e 'Sys.getenv("HOME")'
[1] "/tmp/"
me@mybox:/some/path$ Rscript -e 'Sys.setenv(HOME="/tmp/");Sys.getenv("HOME")'
[1] "/tmp/"
```

(This notably does not work as well on Windows ... which is not very unix-y of it!)

So you can try overriding it with either:

1. `Sys.setenv(HOME = "/Users/my.name/drive/R/project/sub.folder")`, or
2. Set the `HOME` variable in your working environment before starting R.

This might have unintended consequences. For instance, R looks for `~/.Rprofile`, and git and commands look for `~/.gitconfig` and such.

My recommended way-ahead would be to define a variable and change there. If you use RStudio, then its "Projects" can always start you in the correct directory. If not and you still want this "special directory" available to you, perhaps add this to your `/Users/username/.Rprofile` (in your "actual" homedir)

```
.specialdir <- "/Users/my.name/drive/R/project/sub.folder"
```

and, whenever you need to go there, use `file.expand(.specialdir)`. One side-effect of this is that any of your code, functions, reports, whatever that use this will no longer be reproducible.

Comment: (BTW: I chose to prefix it with a dot to hide it from a normal call to `ls()`; it doesn't protect it or limit its use, it takes advantage of R's anti-clutter mechanism of `ls(..., all.names=FALSE)`.)

Answer (score 3):

A way to easily reference your files without needing to change the HOME directory is to use the `here` package. This basically uses a heuristic to find the right working directory based on where your script is. Normally it looks for RStudio Project files (`.rproj`) or for a `.git` file if your working directory is a git repository. It's easy to use and robust to moving machines or accidental use of `setwd`, or even forgetting to set HOME on a different machine/profile.

If your data file `some_data.csv` above is stored in `/Users/my.name/drive/R/project/sub.folder/some_data.csv`, where `project` is the root folder for the project:

```
here::here()
[1] "/Users/my.name/drive/R/project"
here::here("sub.folder", "some_data.csv")
[1] "/Users/my.name/drive/R/project/sub.folder/some_data.csv"
```

and you can use it as a drop in replacement for the path, as in:

```
data <- read_csv(here::here("sub.folder", "some_data.csv"))
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use that over `file.path(getwd(), "sub.folder", "some_data.csv")`? (besides code-golf)

Comment: If your working directory is not set correctly to the root `file.path(getwd())` will not work but `here::here` still will. One place this happens a lot is in R Markdown chunks, where the working directory is the subdirectory of the .Rmd file by default even if you're working in an R project.

Comment: Using here::here() needs to become the standard!